# wix virtual directories under default web site not uninstalled, conflict with other features?

Tags: iis, wix, wix3.5

I am building an installer using wix for several .net web applications. I have two features, one of which installs several virtual directories / applications under default web site in IIS. The second feature creates a separate website with a single virtual directory.

The problem is when I install both features, the virtual directories (from feature 1) under default web site are not removed during the uninstall. The strange part is that if I just install feature 1 (exclude feature 2) the uninstall works properly for feature 1 and the virtual directories are removed.

I am new to wix, I'm guessing something is wrong with my product.wxs or there is something Im not understanding. Thoughts?

Here is a sample snippet from my product.wxs file :

```
<Feature Id="feature1" Title="feature1" Description="feature 1 description" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Display="expand">
  ...
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="IIS_Feature1" />
</Feature>

<Feature Id="feature2" Title="feature2" Description="feature 2 description" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Display="expand">
  ...
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="IIS_Feature2" />
</Feature>
```

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  ...
  <Directory Id="ROOT_DRIVE">
    <Directory Id="Inetpubdir" Name="inetpub">
      <Directory Id="wwwrootdir" Name="wwwroot" />
      <Directory Id="wwwrootcustom" Name="wwwroot-custom" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

```
<ComponentGroup Id="IIS_Feature1">
  <Component Id="IIS_WebApp1" Guid="some-guid-1" Directory="wwwrootdir" KeyPath="yes">
    <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="WebApp1VirtualDir" Alias="webapp1" WebSite="DefaultWebSite" Directory="WEBAPP1DIR">
      <iis:WebApplication Id="WebApp1IISApplication" Name="webapp1" />
    </iis:WebVirtualDir>
  </Component>

  <Component Id="IIS_WebApp2" Guid="some-guid-2" Directory="wwwrootdir" KeyPath="yes">
    <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="WebApp2VirtualDir" Alias="webapp2" WebSite="DefaultWebSite" Directory="WEBAPP2DIR">
      <iis:WebApplication Id="WebApp2IISApplication" Name="webapp2" />
    </iis:WebVirtualDir>
  </Component>

  <Component Id="IIS_WebApp3" Guid="some-guid-3" Directory="wwwrootdir" KeyPath="yes">
    <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="WebApp3VirtualDir" Alias="webapp3" WebSite="DefaultWebSite" Directory="WEBAPP3DIR">
      <iis:WebApplication Id="WebApp3IISApplication" Name="webapp3" />
    </iis:WebVirtualDir>
  </Component>

</ComponentGroup>

<ComponentGroup Id="IIS_Feature2">
  <Component Id="IIS_WebApp4" Guid="some-guid-4" Directory="wwwrootcustom" KeyPath="yes">
    <iis:WebSite Id="WebApp4Site" Description="Web App 4 Site" Directory="wwwrootcustom" AutoStart="yes">
      <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="WebApp4VirtualDir" Alias="webapp4" Directory="WEBAPP4DIR">
        <iis:WebApplication Id="WebApp4IISApplication" Name="webapp4" />
      </iis:WebVirtualDir>
      <iis:WebAddress Id="WebApp4SiteAddr" Secure="yes" Port="443"/>
    </iis:WebSite>
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was discovered during early development of my installer. As more development work was done and other issues resolved, I am no longer seeing this behavior.

I never really figured out exactly what was happening, but I have noticed during testing if one or more things are awry with the installer, certain (seemingly unrelated) components will be left behind during the uninstall...